# Is it possible to use getSingleColumnResult in this queryBuilder

Tags: php, symfony, query-builder

Here is my queryBuilder where I only want to get the first element of my select

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
  ->select('dossier.codeDossier, SUM(a.actif) nb_actif, SUM(a.inactif) nb_inactif')
  ->join('a.dossier', 'dossier')
  ->join('dossier.contrat', 'contrat')
  ->groupBy('dossier.id')
  ->having('nb_actif = 0')
  ->andHaving('nb_inactif > 0')
  ->andWhere('contrat.actif = 1')
  ->getQuery()
  ->getSingleColumnResult();
```

I only want to get the first element of my request from the other side, will the singleColumnresult be a problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get first result you just use the method `getOneOrNullResult()`

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
  ->select('dossier.codeDossier, SUM(a.actif) nb_actif, SUM(a.inactif) nb_inactif')
  ->join('a.dossier', 'dossier')
  ->join('dossier.contrat', 'contrat')
  ->groupBy('dossier.id')
  ->having('nb_actif = 0')
  ->andHaving('nb_inactif > 0')
  ->andWhere('contrat.actif = 1')
  ->getQuery()
  ->setMaxResults(1)
  ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

or

```
$query =  $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
  ->select('dossier.codeDossier, SUM(a.actif) nb_actif, SUM(a.inactif) nb_inactif')
  ->join('a.dossier', 'dossier')
  ->join('dossier.contrat', 'contrat')
  ->groupBy('dossier.id')
  ->having('nb_actif = 0')
  ->andHaving('nb_inactif > 0')
  ->andWhere('contrat.actif = 1')
  ->getQuery();

return count($query->getResult()) > 0 ?  $query->getResult()[0] : []
```